# WCF Service Should allow only custom verbs

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm working in wcf service, which should allow only some custom verbs.
I'm using `[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/path", Method = "VERB", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]` at the interface to receive the request.
My need is the service should allow only **Method = "VERB"**, for other methods it should return **405** as error. It works fine for all the request except **Method = "GET"**. I want to return **405** for **"GET"** also.

Comment: If you want full control, i advise you write your own WCF interceptor class which run on each incoming request. Another solution is to write your own HTTP Module and apply it to IIS app hosting your WCF service. Usually, this is easily done with asp.net web.config files, i assume its not the case with WCF web.config files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created a test project and check your problem. I specified the `Method = "VERB"` and it works just fine. service reject all other methods(including GET). but if you want fully control i suggest use `Method = "*"` and then reject all other invalid methods like this:

```
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod.Equals("VERB", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
    return 405;
```

Comment: In my code, the request with GET method it even not reach the condition to check the verb.